# SnapLogic REST Post with JSON data

Tags: json, http-post, logic, yahoo-api, snaplogic

How do you make a REST Post in SnapLogic with JSON data as the body?

I need to make a Post to yahoo bulk file download endpoint (https://api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest/bulk/download) and the request body has to be in JSON format:

```
{
  "advertiserId": 30944,
  "objectType": "CAMPAIGN",
  "downloadAllLevels": true,
  "filters": {
             "objectIds": [123,
                456
             ],
             "objectStatus": [
                "ACTIVE"
             ],
             "fromDate": "2014-07-01 00:00:00",
             "toDate": "2014-07-10 00:00:00",
                         "includeNegative":true,
                         "includeTargeting":true,
                         "includeExtensions":true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you need to add a JSON Generator object and add your JSON data there.

Then you can attach it to the REST Post object. In the Post object make sure the `HTTP entity` value is set to `$` ($ = the root path) or whatever 
the path is to the JSON data that you want to send.

[image: JsonGenerator]

The post will now be sent with this json data as the body